# Line regression using vectors

Tags: function, vector, regression

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector> 

struct Result
{
  double A;
  double B;
};

class Regression
{

  struct Point 
  {
    double x;
    double y;
  };

  std::vector<Point> points{};

  public:
  void add(double x, double y) 
  {
    Point const p{x, y};
    points.push_back(p);
  }
  
  int N = points.size();

  double sum_x(std::vector<Point> points)
  {
      double sum = 0;
      for (Point n : points){
          sum = sum + n.x;
      }
      return sum;

  }

  //and so on for sum_y, sum_xy, sum_x2 (to shorten the question)

    double sum_x = sum_x(points);
    double sum_y = sum_y(points);
    double sum_xy = sum_xy(points);
    double sum_x2 = sum_x2(points);

 

  Result fit() const
  {
    double const d = (N * sum_x2  - sum_x * sum_x);
    double const a = (sum_y * sum_x2 - sum_x * sum_xy) / d;
    double const b = (N * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / d;
    return {a, b};
  }  
};
```

Hi, I can't make this code work, for every sum_x, sum_y, etc in the function fit() the error states "expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type".
I'm really new to c++ so I apologize if this is a trivial mistake.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The compiler thinks that sum_x is etc. are function, so name the variables in a different way so that they are distinguishable